# Is a C# dynamic POD a value or reference type?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reference, value-type, reference-type

Q: In the example below, is `n` a value or by reference?

```
dynamic n = (int)2;
```

---

By default, unless otherwise specified:

- Class instances, and Arrays, are reference types.
- POD types, and possibly structs, are value types.

Conceptually, the value above could be thought of as a "dynamic POD type", or a "dynamic type containing a POD", either way it's not obvious which of the above rules should apply, if they both apply, this could lead to a contradiction.

To me, `dynamic` feels as if it should behave like the value it holds, or otherwise be a reference type.

Comment: `dynamic` is not a real type, at runtime they are represented as `object`s which are reference types.

Comment: Note for those who don't know (including me until 5 minutes ago): POD = [**P**lain **O**ld **D**ata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dynamic` is same as `object`. Actually if you'll use decompiler (e.g. ILDasm), you will see

```
  object n = 2
```

Or if you prefer IL code

```
.locals init (
    [0] object
)

IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldc.i4.2
IL_0002: box [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_0007: stloc.0
```

So `n` is object and it's a reference type. And yes, you have boxing here. Even C# specification says that dynamic can be considered identical to object (4.7 The dynamic type):

> dynamic is considered identical to object except in the following
> respects:
>
> • Operations on expressions of type dynamic can be dynamically bound (§7.2.2).
>
> • Type inference (§7.5.2) will prefer dynamic over object if both are candidates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'm not sure. Dynamic behaves quite different from Object, due to "Operations on expressions of type dynamic can be dynamically bound (§7.2.2)". But they produce the same IL code, and are the same value/reference type wise. Except, that from the other two answers so far, it seems like somthing, seemingly boxing, gives dynamic the same behaviour/interactions/characteristics as if dynamic values take on the value/reference properties of there value, this is even the case with the "is" keyword.

Comment: @alan2here sorry, didn't get you. You are telling that dynamic object produce same IL code. That's not true. Reference to `dynamic` instance is stored in `object` variable (as you see above), but any calls to that variable are very different. Because instead of producing IL code which do some call on dynamic variable, compiler produces IL code which *describes* call that should be done.

Comment: I thought that was what you were saying, "Dynamic is same as object. Actually if you'll use decompiler (e.g. ILDasm), you will see [code] Or if you prefer IL code [code]". I see your describe in your comment the underlying reasons for the vast difference of behavior between 'dynamic' and 'object'. The bigger issue for me is that they do not act as a reference type, whatever the mechanism (for example boxing), they act as a value or reference type depending on what they hold. See the two answers below.

Comment: No, he's correct in saying that dynamic is the same as object. The only differences are compile-time treatment of the compiler turning code written in the same style as early bound code into late-bound code that uses reflection and expressions. At runtime `dynamic n = 2` is the same as `object n = 2`.

Answer (score -1):

Pleasantly, they seem to be of the sort of type they are holding.

```
dynamic n = (int)2;
```

`is` a value type.

```
dynamic n = new int[0];
```

`is` a reference type.

---

```
dynamic n = 4;
bool b = n is ValueType; // true
n = new int[0];
b = n is ValueType; // false
```

---

See `NineBerry`'s answer for a different sort of example using struct members and not using `is`.

Comment: `n` is of type `object`, though. There's a value type, but it's boxed

Comment: Try `ReferenceEquals(n, n)` and it'll return true. Do that directly with a value type and it'll return false.

Answer (score -1):

Consider this example:

```
struct TestStruct
{
    public int Value;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TestStruct lOriginal = new TestStruct();
    lOriginal.Value = 42;

    dynamic n = lOriginal;
    dynamic m = n;

    lOriginal.Value = "4711"
    MessageBox.Show(m.Value.ToString());

    n.Value = 4711;
    MessageBox.Show(m.Value.ToString());
}
```

The first output is "42". The second output is "4711". So when assigning a value type to the dynamic variable, the value type behaves like a value type, making a copy. But when you then work with the dynamic variable, it behaves as a reference type, only copying references when assigning to another dynamic variable.

Comment: The behavior you're seeing is idential to what you'd see if you use `object`, which is a reference type (which is exactly how `dynamic` stores the value, so of course it's the same).  The behavior you're seeing is simply the behavior of boxing.

Comment: Compare to my reply. Could this boxing be simulating the behavior of dynamic value/reference typing?